# Changing a binary registry value with PowerShell from a .reg file

Tags: powershell, registry

I have exported a registry directory that I would like to use in a PowerShell script. The .reg file contains two very long hex strings that I have been trying to use in `Set-ItemProperty` and `New-ItemProperty`, but neither have been successful. I keep getting errors whenever I run my script because PowerShell seems to have problems with the 'cc' hex values.

Things I have tried:

- Assigning the hex values to a variable and using that in `Set-ItemProperty` and `New-ItemProperty`

  ```
  New-ItemProperty -Path "HKCU:\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\Taskband" -Name "Favorites" -PropertyType BINARY -Value $favorites
  ```
- Putting the hex values directly into the cmdlet with no formatting
- Putting the hex value into the cmdlet with double and single quotes around them
- Removing the old keys and creating new ones with`-PropertyType Binary`

Reg file: https://pastebin.com/rrAzMivQ
PS script: https://pastebin.com/NrQFr71w

Comment: I would not recommend changing binary registry data unless you have a specification of what the data does. What are you actually trying to do?

Comment: If you have the `.reg` file, why not just execute it via PS or even CMD? It is very easy in CMD. `REG /?`

Comment: `[byte[]]00,cc,01,00,00,3a,...` won't do what you expect. You need `[byte[]](0x0, 0xcc, 0x1, 0x0, 0x0, 0x3a, ...)` or `[byte[]](0, 204, 1, 0, 0, 58, ...)`. Also, as was already pointed out, if you already have a .reg file the simplest way would be to import that via `reg import your.reg`.

Comment: Blindly overwriting a binary registry value may have unintended side effects. Not recommended.

Comment: Thanks to everyone who gave advice. The reason I don't want to use the .reg file is because I want to package the PS script as a standalone executable. I think Ansgar Wiechers answered my question. And Bill, ill try not to break anything.

Comment: If you don't know what each of the bits in the binary value does, you are almost guaranteed to break something.

Comment: Please move your solution to an answer of its own, thank you.

Answer (score -1):

#### Solved

I was able to get my script to work. Here is the final result if anyone is interested: https://pastebin.com/PW5Cjy0d

```
"The code is very long. Follow link."
```